# code sign error in xcode, no identity found

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I've looked to solve this problem for several hours now, so hopefully someone can help me.

When I try to Archive my project (so I can put it in the app market), I get a code sign error:

> Codesign failed with exit code 1

and some additional information says

> iPhone Distribution: company name: no identity found

I've created a distribution profile (multiple times) and followed several suggestions (like uninstalling/installing Xcode). Also my distribution profile expiration date is February 2014.

I can Build my project without any problems and run it on an iPhone with my iPhone Developer profile.

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see whether the distribution certificate u downloaded from dev site is in ur keychain access or not

Answer (score 10):

Your Distribution Profile might not be valid or not properly verified, go to `Organizer->Devices->Provisioning Profiles` and try to refresh your profiles(delete & refresh) they will show up after refreshing. Once refreshed, make sure the green icon as status is showing with the profiles if it is valid and signed properly. if it does not solve your problem then you need to create the Distribution profile again.  You could find this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1) helpful if you are getting started with distribution of your app. I hope it helps your cause

Comment: I did the delete/refreshing. They appeared again, but I don't see a green icon as status (there's nothing o see under status). The Archive problem still excists, so I recreated the Distribution Profile again, but this didn't help. I also read the tutoial and it seems I'm taking the right steps. Also if I look in keychain access I see my iPhone Developer and iPhone Distribution profile (with a gray arrow in front). Maybe one thing that shouldn't be here is the iPhone Developer profile of my colleague (he used this computer too), but I can't get rid off his profile.

Comment: one problem could be that you should make sure in your Scheme that you are doing the archive for the release not for the debug level., also try to remove old entries from keychain access and try from scratch again, I know it is mind boggling, I have been in this situation also, I just created everything from scratch also.

Comment: I checked the Scheme to make sure it was set to release. Also I removed all the entries in Keychain access and created everything again. No difference, still the same error.

Comment: But one thing I noticed is that under the iPhone Distribution (in Keychain access) I see my company name in stead of my name. In a technical note of 

Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING_FAQ 

at the "verify your privaste keys" section that for both the Developer as the Distribution the same name is used. CAn this be the problem? And how can I change that?

Comment: yes it can show your company name if the distribution certificate is issued to your company. and are you sure you have separate development provisioning profile (owned by developer), and distribution profile(created by admin with rights, could be on company name)? and what is the status of profiles in Organizer now?

Answer (score 4):

i am not sure why my solution worked, but after hours of trying everything else... i changed code signing settings in both project and target windows. code settings under 'project' shows my provisioning profile (photo below), code settings under 'target' is now set to 'automatic'.  maybe before i had conflicting settings?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue, the reason is after I run other project and `fix the issue` with the other project.

My solution is :

`Xcode` -> `Proferences` -> Choose `Apple IDs` -> Choose `Team` -> `View Details` -> Signing Identities `iOS Development` and `iOS Distribution` reset.

Then Run project to `iphone` it works fine.

Comment: saved my life!!!, for me the problem was downloaded certificates from developer.apple.com were untitled, somehow not valid. So I just go through your path and clicked on Manage Certificates > + button on the left bottom corner, both for developer and dispatch. so auto generated ones worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've got the similar error and found the reason that my **certificate in keychain was not the one that I attached to the provisioning file** in apple developer portal. Because there were two certificates with same name and I downloaded the wrong one. Upon downloading the correct certificate and double clicking to put into keychain solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have been in contact with apple and after a few emails back and forth they found my problem. For some reason (I don't know how this got there) in the Build Settings under Code Signing -> Other Code Signing Flags I had "--keychain keychainname.keychain" written down there. After I removed this my code sign error dissapeared.

Every body thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to create/update a provisioning profile for you new device. Provisioning profiles are associated with devices, once you set that up correctly, you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

I didnt have proper developer/distribution certificate in my keychain. When i installed it to my keychain, issue disappeared!